# Jest - how to get the ID of a setTimeout?

Tags: jestjs, settimeout

I have the following test:

```
it('should have a numerical id set', () => {
  var id = setTimeout(function () {
    console.log(id); //Here
  }, 1000);
  console.log(id);

  // Expectation to be run here.
});
```

The console is logging out this:

```
{
  "_called": false,
  "_destroyed": false,
  "_idleNext": null,
  "_idlePrev": null,
  "_idleStart": 1423,
  "_idleTimeout": -1,
  "_onTimeout": null,
  "_repeat": null,
  "_timerArgs": undefined,
  Symbol(unrefed): false,
  Symbol(asyncId): 160,
  Symbol(triggerId): 0
}
```

Why is it logging this instead of a numerical value and how do I get the numerical value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running with the `node` test environment (either via `testEnvironment` config or `--env=node`), which returns a [`timer`](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html), not an id. If you run using `jsdom` test environment, you'll get a `number` back.

[`testEnvironment` docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#testenvironment-string)

Comment: Thank you for this. So, if if I were to assign the setTimeout to a variable, would value in the timer can i inspect to make sure that it has been cleared?

Comment: Is it the `_idleTimeout` property?

Comment: Found out that, as per the node timer spec, that you can check `_onTimeout` to be `null` which indicates that the the time has been cleared by the `clearTimeout` function. https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/timers.js?source=post_page